# How to convert an integer to a binary representation in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity DistanceCal is
  port( timeIn : in integer;
        Distance : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0));
end DistanceCal;

architecture behav of DistanceCal is
  signal conv_int : std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(timeIn, conv_int'length));
begin
  process(timeIn)
  begin
    conv_int <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned((timeIn*340/2), conv_int'length));
  end process;
  Distance <= conv_int;
end behav;
```

I need to convert an integer to a binary representation, but I don't know the value of the integer. What should I do?

Comment: Now , i can convert it already. Thank you very much for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration of the signal `conv_int` is invalid. At first, you cannot use `conv_int` in the subtype indication on the right side because `conv_int` is not yet defined. You can use other signals (or objects), e.g. `Distance`, which are declared before. And will you have to specify a range with `to` or `downto` and not just the length of the `std_logic_vector`, e.g.:

```
signal conv_int : std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(timeIn, Distance'length)-1);
```

But this **will not work** either, because now the range is not constrained during elaboration because `timeIn` is not a constant. That means, you have to specify the range of the array type `std_logic_vector` at "compile" time.

It would make sense here to have the same range for `conv_int` as for `Distance` because you assign `conv_int` to `Distance` later on. This declaration will be valid:

```
signal conv_int : std_logic_vector(Distance'range);
```

With this change, your code will analyze and elaborate (compile / synthesize). Now your integer to "binary" conversion at this line

```
conv_int <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned((timeIn*340/2), conv_int'length));
```

will work as follows: The integer expression `timeIn*340/2` will be evaluated at simulation time / at run-time, then converted to `unsigned` while truncating the binary representation to `conv_int'length` bits, and finally converting this to `std_logic_vector`. Be aware that for `timeIn` values greater than floor(2**16/170) = 101, the truncation will / may lead to an unexpected `Distance`.

---

The code can be further improved:

1. You should avoid the non-standard Synopsys package `std_logic_unsigned`. Please use the standard IEEE package `numeric_std` only.
2. You process will be equivalent to the one-liner `conv_int <= ...` written as an concurrent statement. Because variants will be executed when `timeIn` changes (and once after startup).
3. You don't need an intermediate signal here, if `conv_int` is only assigned to the output `Distance`.
4. The multiplication by 340/2 will be equivalent to the multiplication by 170, as long as `timeIn` is smaller than 2**31/170. This would be the case due to the above requirements regarding truncation.

Thus, your architecture can be reduced to:

```
architecture behav of DistanceCal is
begin
   Distance <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(timeIn*170, Distance'length));
end behav;
```